# How fill fields using a django forms.ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How I can obtain the Product Name when I select a opcion the Ref field from a django form.

```
 class InvoiceForm(forms.Form):
    invoice= forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput())
    Ref= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.all())
    Product = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput())
```

Comment: you have to use JavaScript to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the name of the product to be automatically filled in based on the `Ref` field. However, in that case you don't need a separate field at all. In the template, the `ModelChoiceField` will display options using the `Producto` class `__str__` method. So maybe something like this would suit your needs.

```
#models.py
class Producto(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#forms.py
class InvoiceForm(forms.Form):
    invoice= forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput())
    product= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Producto.objects.all())

#views.py
class MyFormView(views.FormView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form.cleaned_data['product']
        # can access any product attributes
        if product.name == 'bananas':
            # do_something(form)
```

Keep your field names lowercase (`product` not `Product`), it's best practices.